# Appending items to an array in dictionary not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have this static dictionary created as so:

```
static var pictures = Dictionary<Int, Array<UIImage>>()
```

I want to populate it with images. At the moment when I am creating it I don't know how many key/value pairs I need to create. I have to fetch from the internet the data, but after that I am doing this to populate, but still my dictionary is empty:

```
for i in 0...Fetching.numberOfAliveListings - 1 {
    for _ in 0...AdsCollectionView.listings[i].photos.count - 1 {
        AdsCollectionView.pictures[i]?.append(UIImage(named: "noimage")!)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `..<` operator instead for prevent crash.

Comment: Should I use it on the first for, second for or both?

Comment: Use `..<` for both and remove the `- 1`. Otherwise if there are 0 photos, it tries to access the `-1st` element, which will crash as `"Index is out of range"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pictures` is initially empty. So any attempt to access a value for a given key will result in a `nil` value. Since the value (the array) is `nil`, the optional chaining skips the call to `append`.

One solution is to provide a default array when looking up the value for a given `Int`.

```
AdsCollectionView.pictures[i, default: []].append(UIImage(named: "noimage")!)
```

You may also wish to consider alternate syntax when declaring `pictures`:

```
static var pictures = [Int: [UIImage]]()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly, just had to add () after UIImage in default.